# Data-Format javascript library in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am receiving date in json response and parsing it using [date-format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) javascript library. It's working fine in Firefox but throws exception in IE.

date received from json 
response.actionDateTime : 2012-04-12T18:23:49

here is what I tried

```
dateFormat(response.actionDateTime,"dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:ss")
```

It throws exception on following lines of date format library

```
date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");
```

I am unable to resolve it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally, I came up with following cross browser solution. just parsed string to date.

```
/*
    returns date object from string in dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS format
*/
function parseDate(string) {
    var dateTimeArr = string.split(" ");

    var date = dateTimeArr[0].split("-");
    var time = dateTimeArr[1].split(":");

    var day = parseFloat(date[0]);
    var month = parseFloat(date[1]) - 1;    //months : 0-11
    var year = parseFloat(date[2]);

    var hour = parseFloat(time[0]);
    var minute = parseFloat(time[1]);
    var second = parseFloat(time[2]);

    var dateObj = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

    return dateObj;
```

}

But I am still missing date format library.